# glTexImage2DMultisample causes GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c, opengl, antialiasing

When I try to use glTexImage2DMultisample, OpenGL generates an invalid operation error. I am trying to do this the same way as http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling.

```
    glGenFramebuffers(1,&fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    auto GLuint colorRenderBuffer;
    glGenTextures(1,&colorRenderBuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,colorRenderBuffer);
    glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,4,GL_RGBA,2048,2048,GL_TRUE);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE,colorRenderBuffer,0);
```

Comment: Is `4` greater than `GL_MAX_COLOR_TEXTURE_SAMPLES`?